# How should 'beseech' be used in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

How should 'beseech' be used in a sentence?

Are any of these correct?

> I beseech you to help me find Magrathea.
>
> I beseech your help in finding The Silver Bail of Peace.
>
> I beseech to you help in saving the universe.

Or should it be used in a different way entirely?

Comment: This matter is surely fully covered by any dictionary worthy of its name. Be aware, however, that *beseech* doth the air of antiquity about it have.

Comment: As a result of that antiquity tchrist mentioned, it's more suitable for pairing with *thee* than *you*.

Comment: @Ben actually, you might be more proper given that it is the *formal* third person singular in English.

Comment: @DavidM: Seems like you're right, although [thee is very common as well](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beseech%2Cbeseech+thee%2Cbeseech+you&year_start=1700)

Comment: The past tense is _besought_, which is pronounced very much like _besot_, another antique word meaning 'drunk'.

Comment: @Ben see my answer. It's from the KJV that most of us are still familiar with it … and, oops second person singular …

Comment: @JohnLawler I have a different phoneme in *besought*  with `/ɔ/` than I have in *besot* with `/ɑ/`, and I suspect that you may, too.  (I have no `/ɒ/` at all.) But yes, many people would as a result of this or that merger say those quite similarly. In particular, there are speakers of Southern Californian that have gone further towards erasing any phonemic rounding than any other native speakers I’ve ever heard.

Comment: About half of Americans don't distinguish between /ɔ/ and /a/. I happen to, but that's because I come from E. of the Mississippi.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To directly answer your question, your first two sentences are ok but your third one does not work:

> 1. **RIGHT**: I beseech you to help me find Magrathea.
> 2. **RIGHT**: I beseech your help in finding The Silver Bail of Peace.
> 3. **WRONG**: I beseech to you help in saving the universe.

Your first sentence uses *beseech* according to OED sense 3d,
“To supplicate, entreat, implore a person to do a thing.”

Your second uses it in OED sense 2, “To beg earnestly for, entreat (a thing).”

But your third I cannot parse into anything sensible.

---

## Background

I would generally advise a non-native speaker to avoid *beseech* altogether, because it is virtually unused today [per this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beseech%2Cbesought&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeseech%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbesought%3B%2Cc0):

[image: beseech and besought ngram]

And where it is used is almost in very limited contexts.

The only “modern” context that comes to mind is from the musical [*Godspell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godspell), which has the song [“We Beseech Thee”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iv--XOVV2RY) in it, beginning this way:

> *Father, hear thy children's call
>
>    Humbly at thy feet we fall
>
>    Prodigals confessing all
>
>    We beseech thee, hear us!
>
>    We thy call have disobeyed
>
>    Into paths of sin have strayed
>
>    And repentence have delayed
>
>    We beseech thee, hear us!
>
>    Come sing about  Love!
>
>    That made us first to be
>
>    Come sing about Love!
>
>    That made the stone and tree
>
>    Come sing about Love!
>
>    That draws us lovingly
>
>    We beseech thee, hear us!*

There’s more like that, but you get the idea. Once you’ve got *thee* and *thy* in there, nobody would ever mistake it for contemporary speech.

So *beseech* was [much more popular during the first part of the 18<sup>th</sup> century](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22beseech%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1928,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en) than it is here at the start of the 21<sup>st</sup>. The mild resurgence you see at the right end of the graph above is likely due to intentional archaism.  In his [*Book of the New Sun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_the_New_Sun) published 1980–83, Gene Wolfe writes:

> - The bells began again, ringing in some campanile not far away, calling the few who retained their faith to **beseech** the coming of the New Sun, though it was very early still, the old sun had hardly dropped Urth's veil from his face, and save for the bells the village lay silent.
> - The **beseeching** look remained, and he spoke again.
> - I spoke to him as I might have to some favorite cat upon returning from a journey, and he seemed to welcome me as a cat might, pressing his furry body to the unseen wall and mewing, regarding me with **beseeching** eyes.

Even Tolkien eschewed *beseech* in *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*, using it only in the posthumously published *Silmarillion* alone, which was intended to have an archaic air about it:

> - Who grieved at their long sundering from the Teleri, and **besought** him to bring them to Aman, if they would come.
> - There they built ships, and set sail into the uttermost West upon Turgon’s errand, seeking for Valinor, to ask for pardon and aid of the Valar; and they **besought** the birds of the sea to guide them.
> - And when Turgon heard of this he sent again his messengers to Sirion’s mouths, and **besought** the aid of Círdan the Shipwright.
> - He named himself Wildman of the Woods, and they **besought** him to come and dwell with them; but he said that he had an errand yet unachieved, to seek Finduilas, Orodreth’s daughter of Nargothrond.
> - He took therefore a new name, Turambar, which in the High-elven speech signified Master of Doom; and he **besought** the woodmen to forget that he was a stranger among them or ever bore any other name.
> - They came upon Morwen by the banks of Sirion, and Mablung **besought** her to return to Menegroth; but she was fey, and would not be persuaded.
> - Then Mîm in great fear **besought** Húrin to take what he would, but to spare his life; but Húrin gave no heed to his prayer, and slew him there before the doors of Nargothrond.
> - Therefore I am minded to try that counsel which our forefather Eärendil took of old, to sail into the West, be there ban or no, and to speak to the Valar, even to Manwë himself, if may be, and **beseech** his aid ere all is lost.’

If you insist on using it, I would try to limit it formal writing.  Even then I would restrict it to the sorts of uses shown above by those two 20<sup>th</sup>-century writers.

This is not a verb I would ever encourage non-native speakers to use casually.

Comment: Oh, and for a more modern use of the word (one that’s been incessantly repeating itself in my head ever since this thread was created), there’s Freddie Mercury & Montserrat Caballé’s _The Fallen Priest_ (1988): “I beg you, I beseech you to let go / My Heaven is yours, and Heaven is all I know”.

Answer (score 2):

Beseech can generally take the place of he word *ask* or *beg*.

So, you would say:

> I beseech you to help me.
>   I beg you to help me.
>   I ask you to help me.

It is typically (but not always) followed by a personal pronoun.  Here are [several examples of its usage in sentences.](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/beseech)

As tchrist points out, It is highly antiquated. And, as such is always found in the dialogue of period fiction or video games.

As such, it is frequently partnered with thee and thou. But, this is because the most common usage is in liturgical language. [As has been discussed on this site before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159840/why-did-the-kjv-use-thou-toward-god), God is usually referred to as thou (to engender a sense of intimacy).

If beseeching a King, you might be more proper as the *formal* second person singular.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples from [Beseech in a Sentence - sentence examples](http://wordsinasentence.com/beseech-in-a-sentence/):

> As soon as I reach the driving age, I will beseech my parents to buy me a car.
>
> The walkway was filled with fans who sought to beseech the actor for his autograph.

Source: [Sentence Dictionary](http://wordsinasentence.com/vocabulary-word-list/)

Comment: Welcome, john! These are some good examples, but your answer could be better if you provide more of your own interpretation of how to use *beseech*. I edited your answer to make it clearer that these sentences are a quotation from the resource you linked - when you're writing a question or answer, you can use the symbol that looks like a quote mark to do this.